# Error in seas(AirPassengers) : no output has been generated

Tags: r, runtime-error, rstudio

I am getting this error when I run:

```
library(seasonal)
m <- seas(AirPassengers)
```

I have installed the package.
I have uninstalled R, Rstudio, reinstalled and tried again, same error.

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the package and installing it again? remove.packages("seasonal")

Comment: yes tried that...still no go

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce exactly the same error now but I remember following error after I installed the seasonal package:

> Error in seas(AirPassengers) : could not find function "seas"

After cleaning up my workspace the error was gone.

[image]

Following code is working for me and resulting in the plot below:

```
library(seasonal)
head(AirPassengers)
m <- seas(AirPassengers, regression.aictest = c("td", "easter"))
plot(m)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply,I cleaned the workspace and ran the code but still encountering the error               Error in seas(AirPassengers, regression.aictest = c("td", "easter")) :   no output has been generated